# Sql query calculating column per state average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, subquery

This is my table.

```
   Fund   Industry State    
     1        2      NSW             
     1        2      ACT         
     1        2      VIC          
     1        2      NSW         
     1        2      ACT         
     1        2      VIC         
     1        2      NSW          
     1        2      ACT         
     1        2      VIC
```

I have three calculations to perform. Below is the calculated columns

```
Fund   Industry State  Column1  Column2  Column3  
 1        2      NSW      5       10        
 1        2      ACT      5       10      
 1        2      VIC      5       10      
 1        2      NSW      5       10      
 1        2      ACT      5       10      
 1        2      VIC      5       10      
 1        2      NSW      5       10      
 1        2      ACT      5       10      
 1        2      VIC      5       10
```

i have calculated `column1 as Fund*5` and `Column2 as Industry*5`. The `Column3 is the average of Column1 per state`.i,e

```
NSW is (5+5+5)/3
ACT is (5+5+5)/3
VIC is (5+5+5)/3
```

The final table will be

```
Fund   Industry State  Column1  Column2  Column3  
 1        2      NSW      5       10        5
 1        2      ACT      5       10        5
 1        2      VIC      5       10        5
 1        2      NSW      5       10        5
 1        2      ACT      5       10        5
 1        2      VIC      5       10        5
 1        2      NSW      5       10        5
 1        2      ACT      5       10        5
 1        2      VIC      5       10        5
```

I am able to calculate `column1` and `column2` but not sure how to calculate `column3`.

```
Select distinct Fund, Industry, State, Fund * 5 as Column1, Industry * 5 as Column2 
from fundDetails
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AVG` inside a window function:

```
SELECT Fund,
       Industry,
       State,
       Fund * 5 AS Column1,
       Industry * 5 AS Column2,
       AVG(Fund*5) OVER (PARTITION BY State) AS Column3
FROM fundDetails
```

Comment: Nice and clean.